# Would the addition of an $\omega$-identity rule to the first order identity theory make any difference?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The second order rule of identity that depicts Leibenz definition of identity is

$\forall P (P(x) \leftrightarrow P(y)) \leftrightarrow x=y$,

has two directions: the first being *identity of indiscernibles* and the second called *indiscernibility of identicals*.

Now the first order identity theory with the reflexive axiom and the substitution axiom only captures the second direction.

> Now if to first order identity theory we add the following $\omega$-rule to assure the first direction, would that add any strength to identity theory?

**Identity of indscernibles $\omega$-inference rule:**
Let $\phi_1(X),\phi_2(X),...$ be all formulas in first order logic with the symbol $=$ added to it, in which the symbol $X$ occur free, and only free, and in which the symbol $Y$ doesn't occur. Let $\phi_i(Y|X)$ be the formula obtained by merely replacing some of the occurrences of symbol $X$ in $\phi_i(X)$ by symbol $Y$; Let $\psi(X), \varphi(Y)$ be any formulas in that language in which symbols $X$ and $Y$ occur free and only free respectively; let $\vec{p}$ represent the conjoined string of parameters in formulas $\psi, \varphi, \phi_i$; then:

From: $\big{[}for \ i=1,2,3,..., \\ \forall \vec{p} \ \forall X,Y (\psi(X) \land \varphi(Y) \to  [\phi_i(X) \leftrightarrow \phi_i(Y|X)]) \big{]} $

_________________________________we infer

$ \forall \vec{p} \ \forall X,Y(\psi(X) \land \varphi(Y) \to X=Y)$

Now when we extend this theory, then the formulas containing the added primitives are among formulas in the above rule, much as they'll be with the substitution scheme.

> So for example if we formalize $ZFC$ as an extension of this identity theory, would that have any impact on $ZFC$?